# Form gets reset while submitting in JMeter

Tags: proxy, jmeter, server

When clicked on "Submit" button while recording for Signup page in JMeter to reach step two of Signup page, the page gets refreshed and remains on step one.

However, Signup functionality works perfect when Proxy server is removed.

Comment: show the configuration

Comment: Below is screenshot of my WebApp with explaination:
https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pli/Issue.png/_c80fc581ae294cb2bbfde6138e2a0b5e

Comment: that's your requirements, not your configuration. how have you configured jmeter proxy server?

Comment: Below is the configuration for Proxy:
Firefox > Tool > Options > Settings > Manual Proxy Configuration:
HTTP Proxy: localhost
Port: 8081

Above port details was added to "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" > Port under Workbench

Screenshot from JMeter Test Plan:
https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pli/Configuration.png/_1deb3c912daa4eb0bcbfa120406ae3f1

Comment: depends what is in the HTTP(s) proxy configuration and HTTP request defaults. Give us screen shots of those too.. Make sure everything is being forwarded/redirected and kept alive.